# WPF DataGrid column in VM ConverterParameter binding to data context

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got some fairly convoluted code in my viewmodel that defines columns for a `DataGrid`, as this needs to happen programmatically.

These columns bind to properties on an object (this works fine), but a subset of these need to also utilise a converter that needs to receive the data context of the binding object, i.e. the object that has the `SomeProperty` property. I've attempted this like so:

```
new DataGridCheckBoxColumn()
{
    Header = "SomeProperty",
    Binding = new Binding("SomeProperty") {
        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
        Converter = Application.Current.Resources["MyConverter"] as IValueConverter,
        ConverterParameter = new Binding(".")
    }
}
```

This doesn't work; the converter appears to be provided the instance of `Binding` itself. I can't find a way to extract the value from this. I figured it should work because in the view, specifying no path or a dot path tends to bind to the full object.

I also attempted the following:

```
ConverterParameter = RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(DataGridCheckBoxColumn), 1)
```

I'm not entirely sure what the last integer there is, but none seem to work.

How can I pass the bound object to my converter in this way?

Comment: You may need to set the Binding's Source object explicitly, because inheriting the DataContext value might not work.

Comment: @Clemens I'm not sure how I can specify the source during creation of the columns; the data hasn't been loaded at that point.

Comment: @Dan: A `DataGridColumn` inherits no `DataContext` since it's not a `FrameworkElement` that gets added to the element tree. A `DataTemplate` does though so you could replace your `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` with a `DataGridTemplateColumn` that has a `CellTemplate` and a `CellEditingTemplate`. In the template you can define a `CheckBox` that binds to the source object itself. But why are you creating `DataGridColumns` in a view model?